# OkHttp response 204 with content-type json

Tags: okhttp

When i use okhttp3 ver 4.7.2 to create a json request with third api, I will receive response 204. But when I use asyncHttpClient to create the same json request, I will receive correct data.

This is my code using okhttp3:

```
        MediaType JSON =  MediaType.get("application/json");

        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.HEADERS);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create("{}", JSON);
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(URL).post(body).build();
        System.out.println("Start");
        okhttp3.Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        System.out.println(response.body().string()); // null
        System.out.println(response.code()); // 204
```

This is my code using asyncHttpClient:

```
        ListenableFuture<org.asynchttpclient.Response> whenResponse = client
                .preparePost(URL)
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json").setBody("{}").execute();
        org.asynchttpclient.Response response = whenResponse.get();
        System.out.println(response.getResponseBody()); // Correct response body
        System.out.println(response.getStatusCode()); // 200
```

Answer (score 0):

Request json send by okhttp have conten-type is application/json; charset=utf-8, third api allow only application/json. So their response 204.